# Securing REST Resources with a generic URL Pattern

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, web.xml, jaas

I'm working on a JEE app using REST WS, i would like to secure some specific REST ressources for a specific Role in web.xml

By exemple :
I have four Roles : "Role1", "Role2", "Role3" and "RoleEdit"

I want that only the role "RoleEdit"  can access these specific resources :

```
rest/SomePATH/0/Edit
rest/SomePATH/1/Edit
rest/SomePATH/2/Edit
...
rest/SomePATH/10/Edit
```

and

```
rest/SomeOtherPATH/0/Edit
rest/SomeOtherPATH/1/Edit
rest/SomeOtherPATH/2/Edit
...
rest/SomeOtherPATH/10/Edit
```

the other roles can access :

```
rest/SomePATH/0/query
...
rest/SomeOtherPATH/0/getInfo
...
rest/SomeOtherPATH/0/query
...
rest/SomeOtherPATH/0/getInfo
...
```

I added the following URL Patterns to web.xml for the RoleEdit :

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>EditRessources</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Edit</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*/*/Edit</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>RoleEdit</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

it seems that the Security container doesn't recognize the `"/rest/*/*/Edit"` , so all the other 
roles can acces this last.

is there any way to prevent writing all the ressources in web.xml (just by using a generic pattern ).

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using the [javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/security/RolesAllowed.html) annotation instead?

Comment: thank you @SteveC  , 
i used it and it works fine , i've just added some configuration to the web.xml
servlet adapter
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the probleme, thnx to @SteveC

First `url-pattern` spec are :

> 1. A string beginning with a '/' character and ending with a '/*' suffix is used for path mapping.
> 2. A string beginning with a '*.' prefix is used as an extension mapping.
> 3. A string containing only the '/' character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
> 4. All other strings are used for exact matches only.

source => [Url pattern spec](http://jweavers.com/posts/How_to_configure_Servlet_file_in_web.xml_configuration_file.php) , so the `rest/*/*/path` is not recognized

I suggest to those using jersy RESTFUL API :

1- to add the folowing conf in the web.xml inside the jersey servlet container :

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceFilters</param-name> 
        <param-value>
            com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.RolesAllowedResourceFilterFactory
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
```

2- to use the `javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed` in there WS (securing method or services) :
by exemple :

```
@Path("SomePATH")
public class SampleWS{
   ...

   @POST
   @Path("{layer}/Edit")
   @Produces("application/json")
   @RolesAllowed({"RoleEdit"})
   public String edit(@PathParam("layer")String layer){
       //some code
   }
}
```

that's all.